# Why is the output value of the LM35 temperature sensor unstable when combined with the LDR light sensor on Arduino

Tags: arduino, sensors, arduino-uno, temperature

I tried the LM35 temperature sensor on Arduino and got 28 degrees and 29 degrees. Then try the LDR light sensor and get stable data. But when the two sensors are combined, with the LM35 connected to pin A0 and the LDR sensor connected to A1, the result is that the LM35 output is not stable, 28.29 and 45. Both sensors use a 5 Volt voltage and ground. For the LDR sensor plus a 10 K ohm resistor connected to ground. What is the cause of the unstable?

My code is

```
float temperature;
int lm35=A0;
int ldr=A1;
int ldr_value=0;
void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 pinMode(ldr,INPUT);
 pinMode(lm35,INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  temperature=analogRead(lm35);
  temperature=temperature*(5.0*100.0/1024.0); 

  ldr_value=analogRead(ldr);
  Serial.print("Temperature : ");
  Serial.print(temperature);
  Serial.print(" | ");
  Serial.print("LDR : ");
  Serial.println(ldr_value); 
  delay(1000);
}
```

Drawing of Arduino circuit is:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZzKh.png)

The results of running is :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujYaI.png)

Comment: you're code says A0, A4 while your schematics and post say A0/A1

Comment: ok, now I have changed A4 to A1.